# Perforce Code checkout in windows

Tags: perforce

My perforce server is running on Linux.
I installed Perforce client [command line] on windows. When I try to checkout the files using following commands:

p4 -u user -P passwd sync -f ...

I see that its refreshing all the files but not checking out. It could be related to directory structure problem in windows. [Linux and windows have different directory structures like "a/b" and "a\b".]

Please help me how to checkout the code base in this situation.

Comment: Can you also post how depot is mapped? Have you created a workspace?

Answer (score 1):

If by "refreshing all the files" you mean that you're getting their local copies, then that's exactly what `p4 sync` does. Don't expect it to check files out in the sense of marking them as being worked on by you. For that, use `p4 edit`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Refreshing is not creating any local copies. It see refreshing line for each file in repository and then it does nothing

Comment: Can you post the output of your `p4 sync`?

Comment: I second the request to post the output of the command you ran.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I got the solution to this: We should checkout with full path of depot. Otherwise it does not work. for example: p4 -u user -P passwd sync -f //depot/SourcCode/...

Comment: It would still be helpful if you posted what did _not_ work.